# jquery chained selection based single select into two select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make my 2 `<select>` change their values based on a single `<select>`, for example:

I want my `kodethnajaran` and `kodesemester` change their options value based on my selection on `kodematkul`.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Mata Kuliah</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="kodematkul" id="kodematkul" required>
        <option value="null" selected="selected">-- Pilih --</option>
        <option value='mk001'>Mobile Programming</option>
        <option value='mk003'>Matematika Dasar</option>
        <option value='mkl001'>Logika dan Pemrograman</option>
    </select><br>    
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Tahun Ajaran</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="kodethnajaran" id="kodethnajaran" required>
        <option value="-" selected="selected">-- Pilih --</option>
        <option value='thn001'class='mk001'>2017</option>
        <option value='thn001'class='mk003'>2017</option>
        <option value='thn001'class='mkl001'>2017</option>
        <option value='thn002'class='mk003'>2016</option>
    </select><br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Semester</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="kodesemester" id="kodesemester" required>
        <option value="-" selected="selected">-- Pilih --</option>
        <option value='sem002'class='mk001'></option>
        <option value='sem001'class='mk003'></option>
        <option value='sem001'class='mkl001'></option>
        <option value='sem002'class='mkl001'></option>
        <option value='sem002'class='mk003'></option>
    </select><br>
</div>
```

The code above basically contains only my `<select>`, with data from sql. The script that I tried is:

```js
$("#kodethnajaran,#kodesemester").chained("#kodematkul");
```

I'm not sure if this is applicable, because I tried to implement it based on this demo:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained/demo.html

it seems it can only change 'kodethnajaran' but doesnt change 'kodesemester' value.

Here's the fiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/vu671ubm/

Comment: share the generated html

Comment: @ArunPJohny i added the jsfiddle link

Comment: can you instead select them with id, add them class `dependent-select` and then try `$('.dependent-select').chained('#kodematkul')`

Comment: @Kejt could you explain it a little bit more?i'm not very familiar with javascript and just learned it this afternoon,thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I investigated a little and the reason why your solution was not working as in example was jQuery version, You should use 1.10 to have `chained` working

Here goes codePen http://codepen.io/kejt/pen/NdzZqv?editors=1111

Also I have changed your code a little to work on classes

```
$(".form-control").each(function() {
  $(this).chained($("#kodematkul"));
});
```

The class I have used is just an example, you can add new class for all selects that need to depend on given one. For example `dependant-select` and add this class to all select which should change on the first one update